# Trouble with simple gtk python script

Tags: python

I am new to python and am trying to run a simple program I found on the web. I have installed the pyGTK All In One Download and cannot (after searching on the web for a month or so) find gtk.py anywhere.

It does not exist on my computer no matter how many times i run **pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi**
Here is my code

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Simple:

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        win.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        win.set_title("Simple")
        win.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        win.show_all()

        Simple()
        gtk.main()
```

I searched this forum and many others as well. If you have this file, could you post the code so I can copy it?
If someone can help I would be very grateful. Thank You for listening.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
It seems that I have found the answer from the following link at http://www.slideshare.net/BaabtraMentoringPartner/importerror-dll-load-failed-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-python-mysql. I uninstalled the 64 bit version and installed the 32 bit version. When I run it from the command line the little window comes up! The error still shows up in Netbeans though so maybe the problem is in the  Netbeans IDE?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'm getting the error: ImportError: No module named gtk

Answer (score 2):

The `gtk` code is in

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0
```

There is no single file named `gtk.py`. (There is a `_gtk.pyd`, which is [like a dll](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll)).

However, you should generally not need to access the source code for the libraries you install. Python will handle that for you when you `import gtk`, then you can just use those features within your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another gtk app (like GIMP) you may have problem with enviroment. Also, I hope that the indentation is broken only here, not in your script. And tell us what is the error.

Comment: Hello The error I'm getting is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonscripts\hello.py", line 20, in &lt;module&gt;
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk

Comment: And Yes I do have GIMP installed.Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, the gtk env vars may be set/point to gimp's gtk. Best is to check paths in your enviroments. I don't have a win, but I remember having big problems with gtk when an other app put the path in env vars. I use to manualy set the path to the working libraries, but a windows user may help you with the right path, I don't remember exactly the details

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I checked my env/vars and don't see it containing the path to Gimp. So I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that using python(64bit ) for Windows 7 was the main problem.
So I uninstalled the 64 bit version and installed the 32 bit version and it seems to work fine now.
Thanks to everyone for your help.
I would like to mark this question as answered but I don't exactly know how.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your *all-in-one* and try with this other *all-in-one*:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/

Then:

```
import gi   
gi.require_version('Gtk', '2.0')    
from gi.repository import Gtk
```